# Haskell glib library wont build

Tags: haskell, cabal, glib

When I install glib this is the error that I get. I think my problem has to do with  the "legacy fallback" part but I have no way to fix that.

ghc version: 8.6.5

cabal version: 3.0.0.0

```
$ cabal install glib
Resolving dependencies...
Build profile: -w ghc-8.6.5 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - glib-0.13.8.0 (lib:glib) (requires build)
Starting     glib-0.13.8.0 (all, legacy fallback)
Building     glib-0.13.8.0 (all, legacy fallback)

Failed to build glib-0.13.8.0.
Build log (
/home/dagon/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.6.5/glib-0.13.8.0-83f4ff904d65860d6da22747d08c5e962bdbbd1be59c0e6934c51b56a26d7fa7.log
):
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/cabal-install.-14521/dist-newstyle/tmp/src-14521/glib-0.13.8.0/dist/setup/setup.hs, /tmp/cabal-install.-14521/dist-newstyle/tmp/src-14521/glib-0.13.8.0/dist/setup/Main.o )
Linking /tmp/cabal-install.-14521/dist-newstyle/tmp/src-14521/glib-0.13.8.0/dist/setup/setup ...
Configuring glib-0.13.8.0...
Preprocessing library for glib-0.13.8.0..
c2hs/c/CAST.hs:(1017,5)-(1069,22): Non-exhaustive patterns in function put_

cabal: Failed to build glib-0.13.8.0. See the build log above for details.
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this: glib-0.13.8.0 builds fine with GHC 8.6.5 for me. Maybe your system libraries are incompatible?! You may want to report this on `glib`'s issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

$ rm -rf ~/.cabal ~/.ghc

$ cabal upadte

$ cabal install glib